# Remove [custom-adapter] in favor of [android-adapter]

Tags: discussion, tags

It appears as though nearly everything tagged [custom-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-adapter) really belongs in the [android-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-adapter) tag.

I'm hesitant to suggest [custom-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-adapter) as a synonym for [android-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-adapter) though, because the adapter pattern is used outside of Android as well, which could potentially lead to confusion. There are also currently 14 questions tagged with [custom-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-adapter) but not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

What would be the proper solution for cleaning up this tag?

Comment: What's the problem with leaving the tag alone?

Comment: [android-adapter] is a better tag. "Custom adapter" is like saying "custom class"- pretty much every adapter or class you write will be "custom" because you are writing it yourself. "Custom adapter" could also refer to any implementation of the adapter pattern, whereas an Android adapter is a class that extends a specific `BaseAdapter` class in the framework.